# Trouble with {{ and }} in markdown/octopress

Tags: markdown, octopress

I am using trouble with `{{` and `}}` while using markdown. The code that I am trying to get into my Octopress blog looks like this:

```
<ul id="books">
  <template iterate="book in books">
    <x-book-item book="{{ book }}"></x-book-item>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Except, when it is rendered, the line with the `{{ }}` becomes:

```
<x-book-item book=""></x-book-item>
```

If I change my code to this:

```
<x-book-item book="\{\{ book \}\}"></x-book-item>
```

it renders with as

```
<x-book-item book="\{\{ book \}\}"></x-book-item>
```

I.e., it includes the the `\` and `{`.

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I need to use the `raw` tag here, and that takes care of things nicely.

```
{% raw %}<x-book-item book="{{ book }}"></x-book-item>{% endraw %}
```

produces this on the web page:

```
<x-book-item book="{{ book }}"></x-book-item>
```